# Wrapping section title typesets wrong

Tags: sectioning

I'm using `titlesec` to typeset my section titles.

Here's a picture of the phenomenon:

[image: Wrapping section header title]

The wrapping second line is indented by a significant amount, but I want it to be flush with the first line.

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,onecolumn,notitlepage]{report}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn

\section{Exercise 1: $b$-flow}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Exercise 2: An application of MCFP: rectilinear planar embedding}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

I'm using XeLaTeX to compile it.

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe) that only contains just enough of your original code to be working and able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Off-topic, but it would be better if you load `\usepackage{hyperref}` after the other packages.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with your code.  The headline is split across lines, with the beginnings of the lines aligned left. Please minimize your code, and make sure that it really illustrates the problem.

Comment: @Raven I've reduced it as much as seems feasible.

Comment: @gernot Please look at my reduced example code and better preview.

Comment: with your (reduced) mwe i can't reproduce your problem (tested with recent MikTeX). since you use `section˙, section titles are numbered.

Comment: As explained, that MWE does not produce that output, but just change `\section` by `\section*` in your MWE.

Answer (score 0):

You reduced MWE does not create the result you screenshotted as the use of `\section` will introduce numberings in the headings. I took the liberty to further reduce your MWE to

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \section{Exercise 1: $b$-flow}
        \lipsum[1]

        \columnbreak

        \section{Exercise 2: An application of MCFP: rectilinear planar embedding}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

This will produce
[image: Example01]

When removing the section numbering as shown in your screenshot via `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` and therefore this code

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \section{Exercise 1: $b$-flow}
        \lipsum[1]

        \columnbreak

        \section{Exercise 2: An application of MCFP: rectilinear planar embedding}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I get exactly what I believe is what you want for your headings:
[image: Example02]

Both of the given examples have been compiled with `lualatex` (1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018)) and with `xetex` (3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2018)) yielding the same result.

As you said you were using `titlesec` in order to format your headings I went ahead and added your formatting-commands from your initial code-exmaple (and loading `titlesec` of course):

```
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{1\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0.5\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0.25\baselineskip}{0.25\baselineskip}
```

Though that did not change the outcome of my tests whatsoever.

As others in the comments have stated that they haven't been able to reproduce the problem either I'd say you have to make sure that your TeX-installation is somewhat recent or you have to at least provide some information about the version of your compiler.